# Simplify nested ternary in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
return this.condition1
        ? condition2
          ? true
          : false
        : false
```

Is there a way to write this without using `true` `false`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify that; you don't need *any* ternary operators:

```
return this.condition1 && condition2;
```

Performing a test in order to choose either `true` or `false` is redundant. You can use `!!` to turn a "truthy" value into a boolean value, and if the test expressions already provide boolean values (such as `>` or `<` comparisons) then you've already got the values you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
return this.condition1 && condition2;
```

should be sufficient for using in `if` and other conditions. Note that it's not **strictly** equivalent javascript to your code.

To be certain to return `true` or `false` (as the primitive `boolean` values), you need to coerce this as a boolean like this :

```
return !!(this.condition1 && condition2);
```

(this is really for the sake of exactitude, and I would style recommend the first simpler version in most cases, though).